# Location background Service using GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services, google-api-client

I want to check the coordinates of my users everytime (foreground & background), and in case he's close to a place I'll call my API and send a GCM.

So I have a BroadcastReceiver called after rebooting the device.

```
    <receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This receiver is calling a service in this way:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            LocationService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

This LocationService is using GoogleApiClient for getting the location and checking the distance with my place.

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

When I get a new location I call an IntentService named LocationHandler with this new location

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setFastestInterval(5000L)
            .setInterval(10000L)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(75.0F);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, LocationHandler.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleClient, locationRequest, pendingIntent);
}
```

This handler verifies the distance and calls the API

```
public class LocationHandler extends IntentService {

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    final Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
    if (location != null) {...
```

I think I'm missing something, as this flow is triggered after the reboot but...
How do I call all these steps from the first activity of my app?

Is there something else that I'm doing wrongly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the onReceive() method in the second code block you called startWakefulService to get the ball rolling. If you want to have the same effect from an activity instead of a system-triggered intent, just call startService() in the same manner pointing to your LocationService.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29